# performance differences between shared_mutex.lock and shared_mutex.lock_shared?

Tags: c++, performance, readwritelock

The scenario is: I have two `shared_mutex` for two shared variable `a` `b`, to prevent deadlock, if **thread A** get `mutex_a` but cannot get `mutex_b`, **thread B** get `shared_mutex_b` but cannot get `shared_mutex_a`,  in this case, should **thread A** abandon `mutex_a` or should **thread B** abandon `shared_mutex_b`? Is there any performance difference between the two choice?

```
std::shared_mutex mutex_a, mutex_b;
int a, b;

void foo(){
  mutex_a.lock();
  if(mutex_b.try_lock()){
    do sth();
    mutex_a.unlock();
    mutex_b.unlock();
  }else{
    mutex_a.unlock();        // choice 1
  }
}

void bar(){
  mutex_b.lock_shared();
  if(mutex_a.try_lock_shared()){
    do sth();
    mutex_b.unlock_shared();
    mutex_a.unlock_shared();
  }else{
    mutex_b.unlock_shared();   //choice 2
  }
}
```

I know acquiring the two lock with the same order can prevent deadlock,but that is not the point!

Comment: Both sections of code need the avoidance path as it's not predictable as to which lock is locked first.

Comment: The question is meaningless. Neither of the threads knows whether it is A or B. Both threads should abandon their locks. "I know acquiring the two lock with the same order can prevent deadlock,but that is not the point!": it is *exactly* the point, and there is no other point.

Comment: As @RichardCritten said, both sections need the avoidance path. Just think about, that a third function `void foobar()` with the same structure as `void foo()` is needed. If you are using your "choice 2" you have chance to run into a deadlock again. Same behaviour if it has the same structure as `void bar()` and you use your "choice 1".

Comment: Maybe the code is misleading, my intention is just to wonder `lock/unlock` vs `lock_shared/unlock_shared`, which one is more efficient?

Comment: Base on the efficiency difference, I wanna take different measures. e.g. if `try_lock_shared` failed, I will `unlock_shared` immediately, however if `try_lock` failed, I will retry once.

Comment: The efficiency difference is meaningless too. You're running multithreaded code here, and some of it has to be blocked while the other runs. Unless your critical sections are astoundingly short, the efficiency or otherwise of the semaphore implementation is insignificant. You are barking up several wrong trees here.